# Applescript within automator to output a specified sentence,

Tags: applescript, automator

I need help writing an applescript to run within automator. All it needs to do is It output "This is my document" to the next automator action.

Comment: in Automator, use "execute Applescript" action. this action contains a predefined handler with "input" and can return a value of "input". just do your AS in between. to return "this is my doc", just replace the last "return input" by "return "this is my doc".

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's best to show with an example. Add two appleScript tasks to the Automator window and paste in this code into the first one:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set sentence to "This is my document"
    return sentence
end run
```

... this this into the second one:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with sentence in input -- beacause it could be more than one
        display alert sentence
    end repeat
end run
```

When you hit run (top right corner to run them both in sequence) you'll see that the first script successfully outputs the sentence, and that the other one is showing it with an alert. Hope this answer you question.